# Firebase Authentication Trigger : How to get the domain name

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am using a **Firebase Auth widget** on two different domains - abc.com and abc.in . When a new user is created, I am using a trigger to create a db entry. I want to store the domain information to know through which website did the user sign up (abc.com or abc.in).

```
exports.createAccountDocument = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user,context) => {

// Find whether user signed up on abc.com or abc.in

})
```

Comment: Btw, if my post answered your question, you can indicate that by clicking the √ check at the left.  This helps people see at a glance what has/n't been answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe the originating URL is built into the onCreate method. See the documentation:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_auth_.userbuilder#oncreate

But you could write your own function that passes `window.location.href` from the front end to get the URL from the browser when your user signs up, and attach that information to the user's database entry.

Comment: Great answer! This information is indeed not available in the `onCreate` handler. A custom Cloud Function that you call from the app is the usual way to go.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I appreciate the kudos!  Your answers have been a boon to me; glad to give back to the community.

Comment: @Tedskovsky - that's a bummer. This would change my plans, but thanks for saving my time.

Comment: @user2989148 no problem.  Fwiw, I believe this would be just a few extra lines, passing the url to the data param of a "callable" cloud function, and writing that to your user's db entry.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable